# Alternatives on how to close Fancybox pop-up window

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

I have fancybox showing simple form. If I press Save, everything goes OK and the form saves normally and pop-up closes etc...
But it annoys me that I can't CLOSE that pop-up other way then save it or right click icon (cross icon) in top right corner.

I would like to add a button or a link to close on bottom of page aswell (eg. right of save button)...

I really need this done and I'm out of ideas :S

I've tryed so far:

```
window.parent.$.fancybox.close();
parent.$.fn.fancybox.close();
$.fancybox.close();
parent.$.fancybox.close();
parent.jQuery.fn.fancybox.close();
$.fancybox.close();
```

I used those inside:

```
    $("#BranchDeleteNo").click(function() {
            e.g. =>  $.fancybox.close();
    });
```

Comment: From looking at the docs, the .close() method should do it; can you post some code?

Comment: why you don't update your previous question instead of opening a new one with the same subject?

Comment: Please do not re-ask the same question.  If you need to improve it, you can simply [edit] the current one.

Answer (score 2):

`$.fancybox.close();` should work just fine on `click()` event in Fancybox 1.3.4.
http://fancybox.net/faq question number 5.

Comment: I've tryed that and all other similair combo, I've readed their documents and found nothing usefull :S

Comment: Post your hmtl and js relevant to that part. Not enough info.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just call the close button? `$('#fancybox-close').click()`

Comment: Thinked of that to be honest, but I've got this error `reference to undefined property a.result`

Answer (score 1):

Or try triggering the click:

```
 $('#fancybox-close').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Same suggestion as above, I've tryed this, but it doesn't work, all i get is this from console `reference to undefined property a.result`

Comment: It sounds like you are not calling it then properly in the sequence. You should close it immediately before any of the form saving/submit takes place.  Put it at the top of the function.

Comment: check if you have used something like `jQuery.noConflict()` then, instead of `$('#fancybox_close').trigger('click');` use `jQuery('#fancybox-close').trigger('click');`

Answer (score 1):

You have to call public close method -

```
$("#BranchDeleteNo").click(function() {
    $.fancybox.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when you initiate fancybox, set it to a variable. then call "close" that variable:

```
var fancyBox = $('#popUpLink').fancyBox();
fancyBox.close();
```